# How to fix no sdk build tools installed in cordova android

Tags: android, cordova

i'm having a issue setting up cordova on my mac.

I get this error  `No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.` I have already installed the build tools using android studio. But from what i notice cordova isn't using it when i run 'cordova build android'

my build logs

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/android-sdk/4333796
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/ad8kunle/app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 69

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

my .bash-profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me on my mac.

Add the path to your ~/.bash_profile ( /users/ad8kunle/.bash_profile )

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
```

Quit your terminal and start again